# How to use a dependency injector for instantiating the object passed to a Post action method of an ODataController when using ASP.NET Web API 2.2?

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2

When using OData V4 using ASP.NET Web API 2.2 I often make Post actions as described in [Create an OData v4 Endpoint Using ASP.NET Web API 2.2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-v4/create-an-odata-v4-endpoint). Specifically I have a post action like this on my mind:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Product product)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    db.Products.Add(product);
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    return Created(product);
}
```

As it can be seen, the Post action method receives an object reference for an instance of a Product class. This instance has therefore been created by ASP.NET Web API 2.2. Is there a way to have the instance of Product to be instantiated by an IoC container like for instance Unity instead that the instance will be just trivially new()'ed?

Best regards,

Henrik Dahl

Answer (score 0):

you could try to create a OnActionExecuting event for every controller. In the OnActionExecuting, cast the request to the according view model ([ASP.net MVC 3 - Getting posted JSON data in OnActionExecuting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085208/asp-net-mvc-3-getting-posted-json-data-in-onactionexecuting)) and manually put it into your IoC.
Afterwards resolve the injected object Lazily where you need it.

Since the IoC container do their job when the Controller-Object is created, i don't think there is an IoC which does its injection magic also when a controller function is executed.

Best regards.